# How to seperate wordpress header navigation into side to side by edition Php files?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header, navigation

I want to separate my WordPress menu navigation into both left and right, i have put the menu function into "functions.php" which added the menu from the backend, and frontend will be edited by the "header.php", but i couldn't retrieve the result, can anyone help me ?

my function.php:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'unite' ),
'footer-links' => __( 'Footer Links', 'unite' ), 
'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu','unite' )// secondary nav in footer
    ) );
```

my header.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location'    => 'primary',
'depth'             => 2,
'container'         => 'div',
'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );

wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
'depth'             => 2,
'container'         => 'div',
'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
?>
</div>
</nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

My backend setting:-

[image]

How my layout looks like for now:-

[image]

i want the secondary menu just right next to the primary menu:-
[image]

Comment: `float: right` on logout button

Comment: Read the bootstrap navbar documentation, it tells you how to setup left and right aligned navs in a navbar: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and put the `css`

```
.fullWidth{
    width : 100%;
    margin : 0 auto;
}

.leftClass{
    width : 75%;
    float : left;
}

.rightClass{
    width : 25%;
    float : right;
}
```

add class in `div` tag

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

             <div class="fullWidth">

               <div class="leftClass">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    ); ?>
                </div> <!-- end leftClass -->

                <div class="rightClass">
                   <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
              </div><!-- end rightClass -->
              <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- clear both left and right -->
             </div><!-- end fullWidth -->
            </div>



        </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

Comment: awesome bro, thankss! i think yours working, anyhow, if i wants the right side menu move abit more to the right, i just change the width of the class right?

one more question, if i want to make the separator to the to the left side, do you know how?

Comment: thxs bro you make separator to the left side see                                  steps 1) .fullWidth{width : 100%; margin : 0 auto; background-color:#ccc;}
step 2 ) .leftClass{ width : 60%; float : left; background-color:#fff;}
step 3 ) .rightClass{ width : 35%; float : right; background-color:#fff;}
left side 60% width and right side 35% width total 95% width so 5% width is separator for left side.

Answer (score 0):

its very easy

put the following code to your header where you place those menus

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>

<div class="topmenu"> 
<div class="top-menu-left"> 

<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location'    => 'primary',
'depth'             => 2,
'container'         => 'div',
'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
?>

</div><!--left menu end-->
<div class="top-menu-right"> 

<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
'depth'             => 2,
'container'         => 'div',
'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse',
'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
?>

</div><!--right menu end-->
</div><!--menu wrap-->

</div>
</nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

Then put the bellow code to your themes/themename/style.css

```
.topmenu{width: 1000px;margin: 0 auto;padding-bottom: 28px;}
.top-menu-left{float:left;margin-left: 20px;width:70%;}
.top-menu-right{float:right;margin-right: 20px;width:28%;}
```

Comment: you forgot to give both menu a width...
.top-menu-left{float:left;margin-left: 20px;width:70%;} 
.top-menu-right{float:right;margin-right: 20px;width:28%;}